# mysql select with 3 conditions issue

Tags: php, mysql

Hello my problem is that if i change my ip but i have the same cookie it goes to the else statment and executing the query when it should go to fail. I dont know why it doesnt take the $cookie parameter in calculation.

```
<?php
    require_once('../core/dbconfig.php');
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    $ip_adress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $cookie=$_COOKIE['Cookie'];
    $id_user=$_POST['id_user'];

    $query="Select * from IP_Cookie_Verify where ID_User='$id_user' and Cookie='$cookie' and IP='$ip_adress'";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die("query failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
     if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {      
            echo'fail';             
     }
     else
     {
     $query="Insert into IP_Cookie_Verify (IP,ID_User,Cookie) VALUES ('$ip_adress','$id_user','$cookie')";
                    $result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die("query failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));


     $queryz="Update `users` SET Voturi=Voturi+1 where id='$id_user'";
                    $resultz=mysqli_query($dbc,$queryz) or die("query failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

        $query="Select * from `users` where id='$id_user'";
        $result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die("query failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                    $voturi=$row['Voturi'];
                    }
                    echo''.$voturi.'';
     }
```

Comment: have you tried to use `$_SESSION` instead?

Comment: why are you using cookie if need to use on same page? try with change value $cookie=$_COOKIE['ck_abc'];

Comment: that shouldnt be the problem cause if i echo $cookie it returns me my cookie

Comment: In the query you check for the ip adress. But if you **change** it the query fails and returns no result, so your else condition is executed.

Comment: u're right Manu, dunno how i didnt notice, i changed it and now it works `$query="Select * from IP_Cookie_Verify where ID_User='$id_user' and (Cookie='$cookie' || IP='$ip_adress')";`. U can add it as an aswers so i can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the query you check for the ip adress. But if you **change** it the query fails and returns no result, so your else condition is executed.

Change your query like this:

```
$query="Select * from IP_Cookie_Verify where ID_User='$id_user' and (Cookie='$cookie' OR IP='$ip_adress')";
```